# Cartesian product of 2 ranges in python

Tags: python, cartesian-product

Do you know how to loop over cartesian products of two ranges in python, such as:

```
for i,j in cartesian(100,200):
 print i, j

0,0
0,1
.
.
.
123,197
.
.
99,199
```

Comment: May this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @karthikr could you please post your answer here? thanks

Answer (score 13):

The `product` function will work:

```
from itertools import product
for j in product(range(100), range(200)):
  print j
```

Alternatively, from [the product documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't it as simple as this:

```
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(200):
        print i, j
```

Slightly more optimized version:

```
inner_range = range(200)
for i in range(100):
    for j in inner_range:
        print i, j
```

Comment: which is faster, yours or JLLagrange's?

Comment: Most likely this version since it's the simplest most pure Python solution you can get. Using the product method gives you an extra wrapper so inherently a bit of speed loss but it might omit generating the second range a hundred times. Having that said, any difference is bound to be negligible anyhow.

Comment: Why didn't you use `outer_range = range(100)`?

Comment: The outer range is only used once, the inner range 100 times since it's within the for loop. For cleanless you could but it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: product seems to be a lot faster when iterating over data like numpy arrays.